# Задать атрибут элементу при выполнении определенных условий

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько однотипных блоков:

```
<div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border">
  <span class="result"></span>
  <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
    <tr>
      <td><input class="matrix-cell" type="text" placeholder="c1,1" value="" disabled /></td>
      <td><input class="matrix-cell" type="text" placeholder="c1,2" value="" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="matrix-cell" type="text" placeholder="c2,1" value="" disabled /></td>
      <td><input class="matrix-cell" type="text" placeholder="c2,2" value="" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border">
  <span class="matrix-name-A">A</span>
  <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
    <tr>
      <td><input class="matrix-cell" type="text" placeholder="a1,1" value="" /></td>
      <td><input class="matrix-cell" type="text" placeholder="a1,2" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Задача: если в блоке с классом .b-matrix есть дочерний span с классом .result (или с другим классом), то тегам input в таблице конкретно этого блока задать placeholder - `this.tableBox.input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'c ' + i + ',' + j);` Блоков несколько, соответсвенно должно быть условие - Если есть span с классом result, то получаем а 1,1 а2,2 и т.д., а если класс у span другой, то b 1,1 b 1,2 и т.д.

Думаю, что должно быть как-то так:

```js
(function setPlaceholder() {
  var tableBox = document.querySelector('.b-matrix');
  var input = document.querySelector('input');

  if (tableBox.contains('<span></span>'.className == 'result')) {
    for (var i = 1; i < elem.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 1; j < elem.length; j++) {
        input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'a ' + i + ',' + j);
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

Но пока моих знаний JS недостаточно для решения этой, насколько я понимаю, простой задачи.
Просьба дать рекомендации по ее решению.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: что за `pure-js`?

Comment: @Grundy, это чистый JS без библиотек.

Comment: для этого есть метка `javascript`

Comment: ok. Буду знать.

Comment: @Astor интересная особенность, вы делаете цикл по `elem.legnth`, НО `elem` нигде не объявлена. Как так? Или вы что-то не дописали в код?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, да, Вы правы, не дописал, т.к.  не знал через что прогонять цикл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[функция `querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) позволяет использовать css-селекторы, таким образом можно выбрать сначала все элементы `span` с классом `result`, которые лежат внутри элементов `.b-matrix`. Потом пробежаться по ним и получить родителя: им будет как раз нужный контейнер.

В данном случае нужно использовать именно эту функцию, так как [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) возвращает **первый** подходящий элемент, а не все.

Далее остается просто получить поля вводи из таблицы и присвоить им placeholder

Небольшой пример:

```js
function setPlaceholder() {
  var matrices = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.b-matrix>span.result'),
    function(el) {
      return el.parentNode;
    });
  matrices.forEach(function(matrix) {
    [].forEach.call(matrix.querySelectorAll('tr'),
      function(tr, indexRow) {
        [].forEach.call(tr.querySelectorAll('input'), function(input, indexInput) {
          input.setAttribute('placeholder', `a ${indexRow+1}, ${indexInput+1}`);
        });
      });
  })
}

setPlaceholder();
```

```html
<div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border">
  <span class="result"></span>
  <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" placeholder="c1,1" value="" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" placeholder="c1,2" value="" disabled />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" placeholder="c2,1" value="" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" placeholder="c2,2" value="" disabled />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Обновление:** чтобы сделать код более обобщенным, стоит немного изменить разметку, например, вместо элемента `span` использовать `data-*` атрибуты

```js
function setPlaceholder() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.b-matrix[data-name]'),
    function(matrix) {
      var placeholderStart = matrix.dataset["name"];

      [].forEach.call(matrix.querySelectorAll('tr'),
        function(tr, indexRow) {
          [].forEach.call(tr.querySelectorAll('input'),
            function(input, indexInput) {
              input.setAttribute('placeholder', `${placeholderStart} ${indexRow+1}, ${indexInput+1}`);
            });
        });
    })
}

setPlaceholder();
```

```html
<div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border" data-name="c">
  <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border" data-name="a">
  <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border" data-name="b">
  <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" disabled />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо. Ответ принят. Но как это реализовать, если подобных блоков несколько, у них разные классы у span'ов? Соответственно  в итоге мы должны получить `a ${indexRow+1}, ${indexInput+1}`, b ${indexRow+1}, ${indexInput+1}` и т.д. 
Понимаю, что должно быть условие, но не совсем ясно в каком именно месте данной реализации.

Comment: @Astor, стоит добавить нужную информацию в сам вопрос, с примерами, а так же не стоит принимать вопрос _просто так_ :)

Comment: @Astor, самый просто вариант, писать на каждый случай отдельную функцию, в которой менять нужные элементы

Comment: но ведь это дублирование кода ... Наверняка есть более рациональный способ?:)

Comment: Добавил информацию в вопрос.

Comment: @Astor, мало добавил, _если класс у span другой_ - какой другой? как определить что для этого спана надо именно `b` писать а не `c`? спан есть во всех контейнерах с классом `.b-matrix`?

Comment: Если в блоке с классом b-matrix есть span.result, то "а...", а если span.matrix-name-B, то "b..." .

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40873/discussion-between-grundy-and-astor).